# If a real matrix $P$ is orthogonal, then every zero of the characteristic polynomial of $P$ has modulus equals to $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

well if this question is changed to complex matrix $P$ is unitary then i can easily show that every eigenvalue of $P$ has modulus $1$ by setting $v$ as eigenvector associated to eigenvalue $\lambda$ $$\langle T(v) ,T(v) \rangle = \langle v , v \rangle  = \langle \lambda v , \lambda v \rangle = \lambda \overline{\lambda}\langle v, v \rangle$$ and our result follows.

However, i have trouble visualizing the real matrix as zeroes of char polynomial of real $P$ does not guarantee its a eigenvalue of $P$.

Pls help!

Comment: What are the eigenvalues/vectors of $\pmatrix{\cos t&\sin t\\-\sin t&\cos t}$?

Comment: it is $e^{\pm it}$, and of course their modulus is still $1$... But if our matrix $P$ is inside real space, we cannot define our eigenvalues to be complex isnt it?

Comment: The line above prove the same result for orthogonal matrices. Indeed if the matrix is orthogonal than what is not guaranteed is the eigenvector associated to be real, but if that's the case I don't see where is the problem.

Comment: You don't even need to reinterpret the line for real orthogonal matrices. Every real orthogonal matrix is a unitary matrix. So you have shown every zero of its characteristic polynomial has modulus $1.$